# how to use Jquery UI DatePicker in form processing

Tags: php, forms, jquery-ui, jquery, datepicker

I have used Jquery UI DatePicker for the option in my form to select the birthdate.

However, jquery gives a datepicker in `<div id="datepicker"></div>` tags,

Now i am using it in my form, how can i get its value to make it work for my form processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use instead an  `input` field.

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="mydate"></p>
```

Also you can user `dateFormat` option to format the date:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you try setting the id to an input instead of a div,

```
<input id="datepicker" />
```

does that work for you?